# How to trigger other devices from geofencing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, tracking, android-geofence

I am trying to develop an application, that needs to connect to other users of the same app. Suppose I want to send a notification to all of the users of my app, who are present within 500 meters. How I can implement this feature for my app?

I have checked the Geofencing feature of Google Maps API. I am not sure whether this can help me with this situation. I have thought, I will create a geofence from device A, and when device B is inside the geofence, it will be get notified. So is it possible? If so, then what will be the necessary steps?

Comment: You'll have to share data between devices and the easiest/quickest way to do that for development purposes is to use Firebase.  Each device updates its position to Firebase and all devices receive updates.  Geofencing does not seem applicable here.  Firebase has a pricing plan but for experiments it is free.

Comment: Yes, Firebase with Geofire can be used in your case

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I have already used firebase in my project. I will try to implement that feature using firebase.

Comment: The Geofire seems to be new for me. I'll study for it. Thank you for suggesting that feature. Silversky Technology.